# Using icons instead of combo box

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui

I have a form, in it where is an icon.

Currently, to select between true and false. There is a combo box underneath the icon, however, what I need to do is to be able to switch states depending on the icon in the combo box itself. If the boolean in the database is false, X will appear, BUT if someone clicks on the X the boolean in the database is then set to true, with the icon changing into a tick.

How can I achieve this? I have looked into jquery but it isnt quite what I am looking for.

Cheers.

Comment: What have you tried with jQuery? You can do virtually everything with jQuery when it comes to communicating between the UI and server.

Comment: I have had a look around at what I can use. It seems like I can't find anything/or more to the point not entirely sure of how to approach this problem using Jquery

Comment: jQuery + Ajax can basically do the effect you just told above. Bind a click event in the icon, and set the database via ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is what you are looking for, you just don't know how to take advantage of it.

First you need to setup your form correctly, you can inspire yourself from this:

```
<form>
    <select name="myselectcheckbox" id="myselectcheckbox">
        <option value="X"<?php if($data['myselectcheckbox'] == 'X'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Yes</option>
        <option value=""<?php if($data['myselectcheckbox'] == ''){ echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>No</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

That should do it for the form element, the code for the jQuery will be this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#myselectcheckbox').hide().append('<a href="#" id="myselectedcheckbox_toggler"><img src="checkbox.gif"></a>');
    $('#myselectedcheckbox_toggler').click(function(){
        if($('#myselectcheckbox').val() == 'X'){
            $('#myselectcheckbox').val('');
            $('#myselectedcheckbox_toggler img').attr('src', 'checkbox.gif');
        }else{
            $('#myselectcheckbox').val('X');
            $('#myselectedcheckbox_toggler img').attr('src', 'checkbox-checked.gif');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

That sounds about right, test it out and try to do the rest by yourself. The code is pretty self explanatory, i couldn't help you more than that.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks , correct me if I am wrong, but is this basically a combo box, which JQuery modifies with icons?

Comment: No, Jquery "Hides" the combobox but doesn't disable it (disabled elements are not posted so you just want to hide it) and then the image is linked to the value of the combobox. If you click on the image the value and the image is changed accordingly.

Comment: It's a good method because if your user can't run javascript and thus can't run jquery, the checkbox will still be there for the user to select a value from...

Comment: Ok I have posted an answer at the above, see my code, cant quite get it to work:

Comment: I'm not here to fix your problems for you, you have a valid solution, try to work with it, understand your issues and fix them yourselves or you'll never go far as a programmer...

Answer (score 0):

Amended my code using jquery from another poster.

```
      <script>
$(function(){
    $('#myselectcheckbox').hide().append('<a href="#" id="myselectedcheckbox_toggler"><img src="checkbox.gif"></a>');
    $('#myselectedcheckbox_toggler').click(function(){
        if($('#myselectcheckbox').val() == TRUE){
            $('#myselectcheckbox').val('');
            $('#myselectedcheckbox_toggler').attr('src', 'checkbox.gif');
        }else{
            $('#myselectcheckbox').val(TRUE);
            $('#myselectedcheckbox_toggler').attr('src', 'checkbox-checked.gif');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And

```
  <select name="myselectcheckbox" id="myselectcheckbox">
    <option value="X"<?php if($child_details['IsVaccinatedAgainstDiphtheria']==TRUE){ echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Yes</option>
    <option value=""<?php if($child_details['IsVaccinatedAgainstDiphtheria']==FALSE){ echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>No</option>
```